# Disabling Userinteraction of all views besides one

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I am struck in my project at some task that is I have a view controller in that lot of buttons and webview is there when i click on webview it recognize the gesture and set some size to webview but tere is some buttons are visble in the screen at that time i want to disable the interaction of all other things in view controller except the webview.Similarly like as UIAlertView there also userinteraction disabled with all other things except the alertview.If any body know this please help me...

Answer (score 1):

This will disable user interaction on all views except for the uiwebview

```
for(UIView *currentView in self.view.subviews)
{
     if([currentView isKindOfClass: [UIWebView class]])
     {
          currentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property userInteractionEnabled=YES //or No of any UI Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your webview on a transparent view ( let's name it "coverView" ) , which frame equals to screen's frame. When you present the coverView (with the webview sticked to it) the user will see everything around the webview (because the coverView is transparent), but any interraction with other objects around the webview will be blocked by the coverView.